# Read-only Outlook window via Win32

Tags: c#, winapi, outlook

I have window handle for my Outlook Inspector window. Basically, it's still window, and I want     it to behave like modal, i.e to not respond until I'll release control. I can't use Form.Showdialog() in this case, because it freezes whole application, but I need Outlook resources for other purposes.

Update: I found EnableWindow() function in user32.dll, but it disables whole application, like modal dialog boxes do. Is there possibility to disable only child window, but not parent?

Comment: Are you launching a custom form or an outlook window?

Comment: I'm running outlook window